# Is std::iter::FlatMap.clone() possible?

Tags: rust, clone, flatmap

I am trying to create all possible pairs of items in a `FlatMap`:

```
possible_children.clone().flat_map(|a| possible_children.clone().map(|b| (a,b)))
```

In order to do this, I am trying to clone a `FlatMap` and I see in the documentation that the `FlatMap` struct implements a `clone` method. But it doesn't seem possible to create a `FlatMap` that satisfies the trait bounds.

This is the error I am getting:

```
error: no method named `clone` found for type `std::iter::FlatMap<std::ops::Range<u16>, _, [closure@src/main.rs:30:47: 33:27]>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:37:66
   |
37 |         possible_children.clone().flat_map(|a| possible_children.clone().map(|b| (a,b)))
   |                                                                  ^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `[closure@src/main.rs:30:47: 33:27] : std::clone::Clone`
```

Looking at the documentation I see:

```
impl<I, U, F> Clone for FlatMap<I, U, F>
    where F: Clone, I: Clone, U: Clone + IntoIterator, U::IntoIter: Clone
```

and

```
impl<I, U, F> Iterator for FlatMap<I, U, F>
    where F: FnMut(I::Item) -> U, I: Iterator, U: IntoIterator
```

It looks like `F` is bound by both the `Clone` trait and the `FnMut` trait, but it is not possible for something to implement both `FnMut` and `Clone`.

It seems strange that a method would exist in the documentation that isn't possible to call, so I must be missing something.

Can someone please clarify for me?

MVCE:

```
fn main() {
    let possible_children = (0..10).flat_map(|x| (0..10).map(|y| (x,y)));

    let causes_error = possible_children.clone().flat_map(|a|
        possible_children.clone().map(|b| (a,b) )
    ).collect();

    println!("{:?}",causes_error);
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `possible_children` that you're trying to use which gives that error?

Comment: The actual value of possible_children is somewhat complicated, but this gives the same error:  ` let possible_children = (0..10).flat_map(|x|
        (0..10).map(|y| (x,y) )
    );
`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no inherent reason that a type can't implement both `FnMut` and `Clone`, but it seems that at the moment closures don't implement `Clone`.  Here's a brief [discussion about this from 2015](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2s08aa/cloning_unboxed_closures_which_own_their/).  I haven't (yet) found any more recent discussion.

I was able to construct this example where a `FlatMap` is cloned by implementing `FnMut` on my own struct, which requires unstable features, so a nightly compiler ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=272c27d0bbff9ae7387f23345723e39b&version=nightly&backtrace=0)):

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(fn_traits)]
struct MyFun {
    pub v: usize,
}

impl FnOnce<(usize,)> for MyFun {
    type Output = Option<usize>;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (usize,)) -> Self::Output {
        Some(self.v + 1 + args.0)
    }

}

impl FnMut<(usize,)> for MyFun {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (usize,)) -> Self::Output {
        self.v += 1;
        if self.v % 2 == 0 {
            Some(self.v + args.0)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl Clone for MyFun {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        MyFun{v: self.v}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let possible_children = (0..10).flat_map(MyFun{v:0});
    let pairs = possible_children.clone().flat_map(|x| possible_children.clone().map(move |y| (x,y) ) );
    println!("possible_children={:?}", pairs.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're creating the cartesian product of the set of items in an iterator with that of another. You can use the [`.cartesian_product()` adaptor](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product) from the [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate for that.

Comment: Actually, he wants the cartesian product of two copies of the same iterator. So he's still need to clone the iterator to pass as the second argument to `.cartesian_product()`, no?